# Checking if a given date fits between a range of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

If I have 2 date columns in a table, `startDate` and `endDate`.  How do I return rows where a given date fits between those 2 dates?  For example:

If the given date is `2012-10-25`

It should return the following rows

```
startDate   -   endDate
2012-10-25  -   2012-10-25
2011-09-10  -   2013-11-15
2012-10-20  -   2012-10-25
2012-10-23  -   2012-10-28
2012-09-14  -   2012-10-28
```

from the following rows:

```
startDate   -   endDate
2012-10-25  -   2012-10-25
2011-09-10  -   2013-11-15
2012-01-11  -   2012-10-11
2012-10-20  -   2012-10-25
2012-04-15  -   2012-04-16
2012-05-20  -   2012-05-25
2012-12-01  -   2012-12-10
2012-10-23  -   2012-10-28
2012-09-14  -   2012-10-28
2012-11-13  -   2012-12-15
```

Is this possible with sql?

I am using sql server 2008.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

With SQL Server it's actually as simple as:

```
SELECT startDate, endDate
FROM YourTable
WHERE '2012-10-25' between startDate and endDate
```

Comment: What if i have two date to find that the date between two date is available between this start date or not.

Comment: Like start date is 1 end date is 10 what if i have two date 3 as a start and 6 as end. so can i find that 3 & 6 are between 1 & 10.

Comment: How to add two dates like ('2012-10-25', '2012-10-26') in the query?

Comment: Is there a way to just check if it's after one date without an end date?

Answer (score 5):

Check [BETWEEN](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-BETWEEN.asp) keyword.

Syntax is simple:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM table1
WHERE '2012-10-25' BETWEEN col1 and col2
```

where col1 and col2 are the start and end dates respectively.

Answer (score 0):

for other lappingcheck the following might be interesting

```
Select * from sted where [dbo].[F_LappingDays](Startdate,EndDate,'20121025','20121025')=1


CREATE Function [dbo].[F_LappingDays](@Von1 datetime,@bis1 Datetime,@von2 Datetime,@bis2 Datetime) Returns int as
/*
20110531 Thomas Wassermann
Terminüberschneidungen finden
*/
begin
Declare @Result int

Select @Result  = 0
if (@Von1>=@Von2) and (@bis1<=@Bis2)
    begin
        Select @Result=Cast(@Bis1 - @von1 + 1 as Int)
    end

else if (@Von1<=@Von2) and (@bis1 > @Von2) and (@bis1<=@Bis2)
    begin
        Select @Result=Cast(@Bis1 - @von2 + 1 as Int)
    end

else if (@Von1>=@Von2) and (@von1<=@bis2) and (@bis1>@Bis2)
    begin
        Select @Result=Cast(@Bis2 - @von1 + 1 as Int)
    end

else if (@Von1<@Von2) and (@bis1>@Bis2)
    begin
        Select @Result=Cast(@Bis2 - @von2 + 1 as Int)
    end



Return @Result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the between operator to find the values between two constraints. This also useful to find the dates which is in a range.

```
SELECT startDate, endDate FROM sampleTable WHERE '2012-10-25' between startDate and endDate
```

For more [BETWEEN](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-BETWEEN.asp)