# TSQL query to sum time periods per range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, time

I need to create a query to sum day's hours and night's hours from a range intersec.
For example with this range:

```
8AM-8PM -> day
8PM-8AM -> night
```

and one or more start-end time period:

```
7.30AM 10.00PM
```

I would like to get this values:

```
12 day's hours
2.5 night's hours
```

I don't know which is the bast way to accomplish this function.

Comment: what have you written so far?

Comment: Sorry, I hoped I explained what i need.

Comment: You have told us what you want written for you. I'm asking what YOU have done? Call me a cynic, but it appears to be nothing....

Comment: You could try to come along with F_LappingDays from
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161044/checking-if-a-given-date-fits-between-a-range-of-dates/13161825#13161825
You would have to adapt for getting hours instead of days

Comment: Don't vote for close, it is a good complicated brain teaser.

Comment: Yes, you're right I did not write it yet... I need a suggestion to approach this problem, may i iterate hour by hour or do you think there is better way?

Comment: @casperOne I spend more than 2 hours writing a solution for this. I consider it ia good question. Easy to understand, hard to solve. Only thing missing was an attempt to solve it, which i think is fair due to the complexity. 3 people have voted for it to be reopened. Why did you vote for close ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk "gimme teh codez" questions are closed as "Not A Real Question".  You should not spend so much time answering such questions as they are likely to get closed.

Comment: I really don't understand why... this question is pratical, answerable and really scoped. And I bet most would not be able to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i wrote in my comment, it is a brain teaser. I hope you can combine this with your code.

```
declare @t table(datefrom smalldatetime, dateto smalldatetime)
insert @t values('2012-01-01 10:30', '2012-01-02 09:00')
insert @t values('2012-01-01 08:00', '2012-01-02 20:20')
insert @t values('2012-01-01 19:00', '2012-01-02 13:00')
insert @t values('2012-01-01 20:00', '2012-01-02 00:00')
insert @t values('2012-01-01 23:00', '2012-01-03 00:00')

select datefrom, dateto, day, cast(datediff(minute, datefrom, dateto)/60.0 - day as decimal(9,2)) night
from @t t
cross apply
(select dateadd(day, datediff(hour, '1900-01-01 20:00', datefrom)/24, '1900-01-02 08:00') a,
dateadd(day, datediff(hour, '1901-01-01 09:00', dateto)/24, '1901-01-01 20:00' ) b) c
cross apply 
(select cast(((datediff(hour, a, b) - 12 * datediff(day, a,b)) * 60
+case when a < datefrom then -datediff(minute, a, datefrom) else 0 end
+case when b > dateto then +datediff(minute, b, dateto) else 0 end) / 60.0 as decimal(9,2)) day) e
```

Result:

```
datefrom          dateto               day    night
2012-01-01 10:30  2012-01-02 09:00:00  10.50  12.00
2012-01-01 08:00  2012-01-02 20:20:00  24.00  12.33
2012-01-01 19:00  2012-01-02 13:00:00   6.00  12.00
2012-01-01 20:00  2012-01-02 00:00:00   0.00   4.00
2012-01-01 23:00  2012-01-03 00:00:00  12.00  13.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for adding another answer. But i realized that it seems you only handle time, my other solution operates on several days. Here is a solution that handle time only:

```
declare @t table(timefrom time(0), timeto time(0))
insert @t values('10:30', '21:30')
insert @t values('07:00', '20:20')
insert @t values('19:00', '21:00')
insert @t values('00:00', '23:59')
insert @t values('00:00', '00:00')

select timefrom, timeto, 
cast(dayminutes/60.0 as decimal(5,2)) [day hours]
,cast((datediff(minute, timefrom, timeto) - a.dayminutes)/60.0 as decimal(5,2)) [night hours]
from @t
cross apply
(select datediff(minute, case when timefrom > '08:00' then timefrom else '08:00' end
,case when timeto < '20:00' then case when 
timeto < '08:00' then '08:00' else timeto end else '20:00' end ) dayminutes) a
```

Result:

```
timefrom    timeto    day hours  night hours
10:30:00    21:30:00  9.50       1.50
07:00:00    20:20:00  12.00      1.33
19:00:00    21:00:00  1.00       1.00
00:00:00    23:59:00  12.00      11.98
00:00:00    00:00:00  0.00       0.00
```

Comment: I accept the other answer because i think it is more flexible. Thank you very very much... I needed just a suggestion, you bring me a ready to use code!

Comment: I am glad to hear that, was considering replacing the other answer with this one.