# Is there any sql query for select specific date from two columns of datebegin and dateend

Tags: sql

I have table of dates like this one below:

I have date `2013.01.20`

And I have another table with these columns:

```
 datebegin| dateend
+------------+-----------
| 2013-01-19 | 2013-01-30
| 2013-01-06 | 2013-01-18
```

So result should be :

```
| 2013-01-19 | 2013-01-30
```

So how can I get my date that exist beetwen range datebegin | dateend.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @prime11 What database you are using, what have you tried ?

Comment: tag your dbms name and use correct date format

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13161088/11878472, check this, looks like already asked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a given date fits between a range of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161044/checking-if-a-given-date-fits-between-a-range-of-dates)

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use `Between` here in query as below.
- Demo -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ig5HCcvRnBSkEq3oHkjZe4/2

```
create table table1 (
    thedate date
);

insert into table1 values
('2013-01-19'),
('2013-01-20');

create table table2 (
    datebegin date,
    dateend date
);

insert into table2 values
('2013-01-19', '2013-01-30'),
('2013-01-06', '2013-01-18');

select t2.*
from table1 as t1 
join table2 as t2
on t1.thedate between t2.datebegin and t2.dateend;
```

Answer (score 0):

why you can not use comparison?

```
select datebegin, dateend
from table1
where databegin < '2013-01-20' and dateend > '2013-01-20'
```